# regular expression replace (if pattern found replace symbol for symbol)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, replace

I have several lines of text (RNA sequence), I want to make a matrix regarding conservation of characters, because they are aligned according similarity.

But I have several gaps (`-`) which actually mean missing a whole structure (e.g.`#- > 100`) If this happens I want to change that for dots (other symbol for making a distinguishment) with the same amount found.

I thought I can do this with regular expression, but I am not able to replace only the pattern, or when I do so, I replace everything but with the incorrect number of dots.

My code looks like this:

```
with alnfile as f_in:
     if re.search('-{100,}', elem,):
            elem = re.sub('-{100,}','.', elem, ) #failed alternative*len(m.groups(x)), elem)
            print len(elem)  # check if I am keeping the lenghth of my sequence
            print elem[0:100]  # check the start

            f1.write(elem)
```

if my file is:

```
ONE ----(*100)atgtgca----(*20)
```

I am getting:

```
ONE ..(*100)atgtgca----(*20)
```

My other change was only dots then I get:

```
ONE ....(*100)atgtgca....(*20)
```

WHAT I NEED:

```
ONE ....(*100)atgtgca----(*20)
```

I know that I am missing something, but I can not figure it out? Is there a flag or something that help me or would allow the exact change of this?

Comment: sorry that was one try:
m = re.search('-{100,}', elem,)
for x in range(1,len(m.groups(x))) .... But that did not work ( I should take that out)

Comment: Do you realize the `-{100,}` matches 100 and more hyphens? Do you want to replace just these substrings?

Comment: yes, I only want to replace "-" that are 100 to more in a road for ".", everything less than that should stay as -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
data = "ONE " + "-" * 100 + "atgtgca" + "-" * 20
print re.sub(r'-{100,}', lambda x: '.' * len(x.group(0)), data)
```

This would display:

```
ONE ....................................................................................................atgtgca--------------------
```

Comment: ...I do not understand the use of lambda x?

Comment: I think you didn't copy it correctly, you have `X` and `x`, they need to be the same. I suggest you copy/paste off the screen.

Comment: `lambda` is just used as a sort of throw away function. It could be replaced with a separate function.

Comment: IT WORKED :) ... I have to learn about this lambda ... Thank you!

Comment: Great, I'm glad it solved your problem. Don't forget to click the tick by your accepted answer when you're done.